# Incorrect Parsed Date

Tags: java, netbeans

**My code:**

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");

Date Today = format.parse(today);
Date Date = format.parse(date);

difference = (Date.getTime() - Today.getTime()) / 86400000;
Math.abs(difference);
System.out.println(String.valueOf("date" + date));
System.out.println(String.valueOf("date" + Date));
System.out.println(String.valueOf("date" + today));
System.out.println(String.valueOf("date" + Today));
```

**The output:**
date29/11/2016
dateSun Dec 27 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2015
date20/11/2016
dateSun Dec 27 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2015

I have problems while parsing the date, the original date is *29/11/2016*, however when parsed, the date becomes *Sun Dec 27 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2015*.
This problem appears in my whole program whenevr it's related to date.

[image]

Comment: Do not show screenshot of your code. Paste the source code into the question in a code block.

Comment: @Andreas done..

Comment: Unrelated, but this `Math.abs(difference);` is a NoOp.

Comment: @Henry my main concern right now is unable to parse the date into correct output. The Math.abs(difference); is just what my system needs to do.

Comment: @JeosiyyChu I meant is has no effect whatsoever. You probably wanted to write `difference=Math.abs(difference);`.

Comment: @Henry Alright. But the problem prior to the math difference is the parsing of the date. It give error output which I couldn't solve.

Comment: Format `dd/MM/YYYY` should be `dd/MM/yyyy`. See javadoc of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): y = Year, Y = Week year.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Syntax and logic errors aside, what result are you actually looking for with that difference and division?

Comment: @Andreas thank you resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format dd/MM/YYYY should be dd/MM/yyyy. See javadoc of SimpleDateFormat: y = Year, Y = Week year. – **Andreas 12 mins ago**

Thanks resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I know you got your solution from [Andreas’ comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701840/incorrect-parsed-date/45864906#comment68632291_40701840) already. What I want to do here is take a step back and suggest a few improvements to your code. Feel free to ignore.

1. Most importantly I suggest you throw the long outdated classes `Date`, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` overboard and start using their modern replacements. These came out in the `java.time` package early in 2014. These also offer a much more straightforward and clear way of calculating the difference.
2. Follow the convention that says that a variable name begins with a lowercase letter. Specifically, in the same source file to use a class called `Date` and two variable called `date` and `Date` is bound to cause confusion.
3. Like Henry I also think you intended `difference = Math.abs(difference);`.
4. Your calls to `String.valueOf()` are superfluous and just seem to make the code a bit harder to read. Drop them.

For the sake of the example, in the code I suggest below, I am deliberately using your incorrect date format pattern string, `dd/MM/YYYY`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY");

    LocalDate todayAsLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(today, format);
    LocalDate dateAsLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(date, format);

    difference = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(todayAsLocalDate, dateAsLocalDate);
    difference = Math.abs(difference);
    System.out.println("date " + date);
    System.out.println("date " + dateAsLocalDate);
    System.out.println("date " + today);
    System.out.println("date " + todayAsLocalDate);
    System.out.println(difference);
```

As the code stands now, it throws a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20/11/2016' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2016, MonthOfYear=11, DayOfMonth=20},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`. When the code is incorrect, I much prefer an exception over an incorrect result that might go unnoticed. So this is better than what `SimpleDateFormat` gave you.

While the message is not easy to read, the bit to notice is `WeekBasedYear`. Week-based years are only useful with week numbers, you intended none of that. If you compare with [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), you will see that uppercase `Y` in the pattern is week-based-year while lowercase `y` is year-of-era. So let’s correct:

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Now the code prints:

```
date 29/11/2016
date 2016-11-29
date 20/11/2016
date 2016-11-20
9
```

We note one final advantage of the modern classes: you can have a date without a time-of-day when this is what you need, again giving code that models your requirements more precisely and thereby leaves less room for confusion.

**Question: can I use the modern classes with my Java version?**

If using at least Java **6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library, the backport of the new classes (that’s “ThreeTen” for [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where the modern API was first defined).
- On Android, use the Android edition of [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). It’s called [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), and I think that there’s a wonderful explanation in this question: [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).